# Swapping two pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to write a function that takes two pointers as arguments and then makes the first pointer point to the object the second pointer was pointing to and the second to the object pointed to by the first.

```
void swap(int *x, int *y)
{
    int *s;
    s = x;
    x = y;
    y = s;
}
```

In the main function, I'll do something like

```
int x, y;
swap(&x, &y);
std::cout << &x << " " << &y << std::endl;
```

But it seems like the addresses don't change.

If instead I dereference the pointers and try to change the values, the values are swapped as expected. I'm wondering why this function won't change where the pointers point to.

Comment: Please don't call your function void.

Comment: Just use `std::swap()`: it swaps arbitrary objects as long as they are regular. BTW, it takes its arguments by reference so the change affects the argument and not just the local variables.

Comment: Oops. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Your code makes no sense: `&x` is an rvalue, you can't reassign it meaningfully.

Comment: Further, no matter WHAT you do, the address of `x` and the address of `y` will NOT change. These addresses are given by the compiler, and no amount of coding will change that. In other words, printout the value of `&x` or `&y` will not change before/after a call to swap (or any other function). If `x` and  `y` are local variables in a function, and you call the function from different places, `x` and `y`'s address will vary depending on usage of stack-space, but their address relative to each other will be constant.

Comment: Is it possible to pass an argument that are references to the pointers and try to assign the addresses to each other?

Comment: @Comrade: Yes, but not for pointers that are rvalues because non-const references cannot be bound to rvalues, and const references cannot be reassigned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function accepts the pointers by value, so any modification it makes will not be visible after it returns. In effect you are swapping the values of *copies* of the pointers.

Comment: Is there a way to write the parameters so that they accept a reference to the pointers?

Comment: @Comrade: You can of course write `swap(int*& x, int*& y)`, but that would still not allow you to swap the pointers to `x` and `y` in main because those are immutable (in C++ parlance, "rvalues"). It would allow you to successfully swap two mutable pointers though ([see an example here](http://ideone.com/f6B70X)).

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Was actually trying something like this but was missing the second line in main().

Answer (score 4):

What you're trying to do is [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap)

```
template <class T> void swap ( T& a, T& b )
{
  T c(a); a=b; b=c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will almost always make your own work more difficult when you use the same variable name to mean two different things.

**Outside** your function, `x` is an `int`.
**Inside** your function `x` is a `pointer-to-int`.
That is the source of your confusion and trouble.

My code below does *not* swap the addresses of the variables.
*(indeed, I believe that is impossible;  The compiler decides the address of `x`.  You cannot change that.
You can only change the value stored at that address.)*

But I think this is what you want:

```
void swap(int *ptr_x, int *ptr_y)
{
    int temp;
    temp = *ptr_x;
    *ptr_x = *ptr_y;
    *ptr_y = temp;
}

int main(void)
{
    int x=5, y=9;
    swap(&x, &y);
    std::cout << &x << " " << &y << std::endl;  // Sorry, Address of X and Y will always be the same
    std::cout << x << " " << y << std::endl;  // Now x is 9 and y is 5.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was trying to write a function that switched the address of x and y. But from what you are saying this is not possible.

Comment: Correct, I believe that is impossible.  Do you have a good reason for wanting to do this?

Comment: No particular reason.