# Swap the pointer in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

Recently I am learning the Link-List in C++.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node{
    Node* next;
    int num;

public:
    Node(int num){
        this->num = num;
    }

    void connect(Node* next){
        this->next = next;
    }

    Node* next_node(){
        return next;
    }

    void COUT(){
        cout<<this->num<<endl;
    }

};


void swap(Node* n1,Node* n2){
    static Node* n = n1;
    n1 = n2;
    n2 = n;

}

class List{

    Node* head;
    Node* last;

public:
    List(){
        head = 0;
        last = 0;
    }

    void insert(Node* n){
        if(head==0){
            head = n;
            last = n;
        }

        else{
           last->connect(n);
           last = n;
        }

    }

    void swap_head_last(){
        swap(head,last);
    }

};






int main()
{

    List* LL = new List();
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        LL->insert(new Node(i));
    }

    LL->swap_head_last();



    return 0;
}
```

There were no errors until I tried to make "void swap_head_last()".
What I want to do in this function is to make pointer "*head" point to the end of this list, and also make pointer "*last" point to the beginning of this list.

But when I tried to print these two pointer's value after calling this function, I found it is still point to the same object.

I've checked these two pages,

[Swapping two pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498582/swapping-two-pointers)

[C++ Swapping Pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672805/c-swapping-pointers)

But what I want is to change these two pointers direction rather than the object's value the pointer points to.

I know if I modify this function as below:

```
void swap_head_last(){
    static Node* n = head;
    head = last;
    last = n;
}
```

The result would be correct.

What's the problem in this function?

Comment: `static Node* n = n1;` is initialized only once, remove the `static` keyword

Comment: The linked list in C++ is `std::list<int> l`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Maybe, but it's very little educational power in just using a class from the shelf.

Comment: @skyking: I disagree.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You're welcome do disagree, but what do you learn about linked lists by just using `std::list<int>`? You could of course examine the sources, but you're probably more likely to get anything useful out of a text-book and experimenting on your own.

Comment: You learn about how to write actual C++ programs. Much more useful.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, but that's probably not what he is learning at this point. By only using solutions provided by others (especially if you don't disect them) you will only learn to use solutions provided by others, which is not that useful.

Comment: @skyking: You're misunderstanding me. Oh well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The root problem is that you can't easily swap nodes in a singly linked list. Actually the problem is that when moving away a node from it's position the successor of the predecessor has to be modified.

In addition your attempt on implementing swap does nothing, it just swaps two local variables (which will be forgotten as soon as the function has finished).

Instead you could use references to be able to swap:

```
void swap(Node*& n1, Node*& n2)
{
    Node* n = n1;
    n1 = n2;
    n2 = n;
}
```

But as pointed out this will still leave the problem that only the `head` and `last` will be swapped. The penultimate element will still have it's successor be the old ultimate element, you will have to update that pointer as well.

Comment: Could have just used `std::swap` from `<algorithm>`

Comment: @thab Yes, but I don't think that the one doesn't learn as much from that. If he went for using ready solutions to the problems he wouldn't run into these problem and he wouldn't really learn anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
void swap(Node** n1,Node** n2){
    Node* n = *n1;
    *n1 = *n2;
    *n2 = n;
}
```

Explination:
If you would have to swap two integer you would need void swap(int*, int*).

Thus If you need to swap pointers,  you would need void swap(int**, int**).

Is not very intuitive at first.

Comment: A good reason why we _don't_ do this in C++. It's old C magic. Use references in C++ for great success. Or, well, `std::swap`.